# Ma che sei grullo?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, regional, english-comparison

Does anyone know if the right meaning of **Ma che sei grullo?** is something similar to *but are you crazy?!*

An Italian friend used this expression and I understood this by context, also checked on the net, but couldn't confirm it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Treccani vocabulary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/grullo/):

> **grullo** agg. [etimo incerto], tosc. – 1. Sciocco, semplicione; si dice soprattutto di persona che ha scarsa vivacità d’intelletto e di chi per eccessiva ingenuità si lascia facilmente ingannare o agisce a proprio svantaggio: *quanto sei g.!; sei davvero g. se non capisci; sarei grulla se ti dessi retta;* spesso sostantivato: *è un povero g.; soltanto i g. possono credere alle sue parole*. Con senso attenuato: *non fare il g.!; sei stato g. a non accettare*.

(my translation:)

> **grullo** adj. [uncertain etymology], Tuscan – 1. Stupid, simple; usually said of person with slow intellect and who, due to excessive naivety is easily cheated or acts against their own interests: *quanto sei g.!* (how stupid you are); *sei davvero g. se non capisci* (you're really stupid if you you do not understand); *sarei grulla se ti dessi retta* (I'd be stupid if I paid attention to you)*; often as a noun: *è un povero g.* (he's a poor idiot); *soltanto i g. possono credere alle sue parole* (only the stupid could believe his words). In a weakened sense: *non fare il g.!* (don't be an idiot); *sei stato g. a non accettare* (you had been stupid not to accept).

So *Ma che, sei grullo?* could be roughly translated as *are you an idiot or what?*

Comment: +1 - I'd just like to stress – even if it is already in the quoted definition – that it is a very recognisably Tuscan term, so it'd be used almost only by Tuscans or by people who like the ring of it.

Comment: @DaG I just added the tag "regional" to the question to stress it as well.

Comment: I would have translated it with "dumb", too

Comment: Additionally it can be used as a confirmation (the implication being that it is foolish to even ask the question): "Oggi è sabato: hai prenotato in pizzeria?" "Ma che sei grullo? Ho prenotato sì!". The familiarity of the expression is more or less on par with *is the Pope Catholic?* or something about the habits of wood-dwelling ursines. Perversely, the same form in the first person is used to *negate*: "Ma che **sono** grullo?" (*(do you think) I am crazy (, to do that)*?)